# Modify the value for laravel 5.1 form input with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have it working with java script and html but when i use laravel forms it wont work

java script

```
  document.getElementById('user-image').setAttribute('value', res.path);
```

html:

```
<input  id="user-image" value="">
```

with laravel form then i cant seem to get it to change the value

```
{!! Form::hidden('user-image', '', array('id' => 'user-image')) !!}
```

Comment: Could you show the generated code? Notice Html Forms are not part of Laravel anymore. To use it, you should *require* **"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"** with `composer`. I tried your code with no problems in my environment. The value changes as expected.

Comment: i get <input id="user-image" name="user-image" value="" type="hidden">

Comment: i just removed laravelcollective/html": "5.1.* and used composer again and its fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.